# Sending silient data message to an Android app

Tags: android, notifications

I am very new to android app development and am wondering if there is a way to silently push a data message to a user's phone.

Basically, I have managed to set up Firebase notification on my app, and the app is able to receive notifications when the app is not running in the foreground.  However, I want to be able to update some data in the user's phone without the user seeing a notification.  Is this doable?
Thanks!!!

Comment: yes, in your firebase service class do not call notification builder method. just change data as you want

Answer (score 0):

yes it is doable.You can send data by calling your api in async task without informing the user and update the data in application without informing the user.
But this will happen only when the application is in foreground.

2nd method is to use service and update your data even after the app is not in foreground.
I will personally prefer to use service.

Answer (score 0):

To do that you need to send the message payload with data payload instead of notification to the firbase from your server where the notification payloads get generated.

{ 
     "to" : "bk3RNwTe3H0:CI2k_HHwgIpoDKCIZvvDMExUdFQ3P1...",
     "data" : {
     "Nick" : "Mario",
     "body" : "great match!",
     "Room" : "PortugalVSDenmark"
   },
 }

So that you will receive the message in the Firebase service class inside onMessageReceived(). Once the data received then using key values you can get the data.

Refer the link to know more

https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/concept-options#data_messages